# Retrieve data from database android error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to use a sqlite database but the problem shows "no such table", the code works on some devices and some show that message.

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final String mDatabaseName;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final String mPath;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context, String database, String path){
        super(context,database,null,1);
        this.mContext=context;
        this.mDatabaseName=database;
        this.mPath=path;
        _createDatabase();

    }

    private void _createDatabase() {
        if(_checkDatabase()){
            return;
        }
        getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            _copyDatabase();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    private void _copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(mDatabaseName);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mPath+mDatabaseName);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        do{
            int n;
            if((n=inputStream.read(bytes)) <= 0){
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                return;
            }
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes,0,n);
        }while (true);

    }

    private boolean _checkDatabase() {
        return mContext.getDatabasePath(mDatabaseName).exists();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

And database adapter look this

```
class DatabaseAdapter
{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;


    DatabaseAdapter(Context context, String database, String path){
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, database, path);
    }

    void open(){
        try{
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }
    boolean isOpened()
    {
        return this.database != null && this.database.isOpen();
    }

    Cursor _get_rows()
    {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM rows ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4;", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

And database controller look this

```
public class DatabaseController {
    private static DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;

    public static Cursor _get_rows()
    {
        if(!databaseAdapter.isOpened()){
            databaseAdapter.open();
        }
        return databaseAdapter._get_rows();
    }

    public static void initilization(Context activity) {
        String dbName=  "data.db";
        databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(),dbName,"/data/data/"+activity.getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/databases/");
    }

}
```

i use in activity like this

```
DatabaseController.initilization(this);
        Cursor c = DatabaseController._get_rows();
```

I could not find a solution to this problem, the database was already copied to the entire directory

Comment: Where is the code of create Table?

Comment: I have a database in the folder "assets" The data file was copied using the "_copyDatabase ()" in class "databaseHelper" to the database path

Comment: when i test on "Samsung s9" device it work but on "lt" Device not work throw exception no such table

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issues is that you are trapping an exception in :-

```
private void _createDatabase() {
    if(_checkDatabase()){
        return;
    }
    getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        _copyDatabase();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

So processing continues and an empty database is created and hence no table.

The root cause might be that the databases directory might not exist. You need to look at the exception that has been trapped to determine the exact error. e.g. `e.printStackTrace();`

The following is how you could create the databases directory (to resolve the `ENOENT (No such file or directory)` exception that may be the issue) :-
e.g.

```
private void _copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(mPath); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    if(!dir.exists()) { //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        dir.mkdirs(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    } //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(mDatabaseName);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mPath+mDatabaseName);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    do{
        int n;
        if((n=inputStream.read(bytes)) <= 0){
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            return;
        }
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes,0,n);
    }while (true);
}
```

It is also inadvisable to hard code paths e.g. using :-

```
databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(),dbName,"/data/data/"+activity.getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/databases/");
```

It's better to get the path using the Context's [getDatabasePath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) method.

- Note the code is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run and may therefore contain errors.
- Note on the devices on which you have issues you will need to delete the database (Clear the App's data or uninstall the App) before running any amended code.

Comment: Copy the database to the path successfully, all the tables exist, but the problem in the data querying from the tables, some devices work and but some devices show exception "no such table"